# Closed collections of finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of (isomorphism classes of) finite groups with the following properties:

1. If $G\in\mathcal{C}$ and $H$ is a homomorphic image of $G$, then $H\in\mathcal{C}$
2. If $G\in\mathcal{C}$ and $H\subseteq G$, then $H\in\mathcal{C}$
3. If $G,H\in\mathcal{C}$, then $G\times H\in\mathcal{C}$

$\mathcal{C}=\text{collection of all finite solvable groups}$ is such a collection. Let's call these collections *closed*.

Let $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$ be called a *basis* if:

1. Every $G\in\mathcal{C}$, $G\cong\prod_i E_i$ for some finite subset $\{E_i\}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ (where $\prod$ refers to the external direct product).
2. Every $E$ in $\mathcal{B}$ is indecomposable; it cannot be written as a direct product of proper subgroups.

**Example:** The closed collection formed by the finite abelian groups have a basis, namely the cyclic groups of prime-power order.

**Question:** Which closed collections have a basis?

*Edit:* @BenjaminSteinberg pointed out in the comments that one could simply take the indecomposable groups in $\mathcal{C}$ as a basis. He also noted that what I called "closed collections" are better known as "pseudovarieties".

**Question:** What are some concrete examples of pseudovarieties whose bases have an "interesting" or "nice" description? I know I'm being vague here, but I think this question is interesting anyway.

Comment: These are called pseudovarieties of groups

Comment: If you have a pseudovariety of nilpotent groups you can take all the indecomposable p-groups (for some prime p) in the pseudovariety as a base.

Comment: I guess by Remak’s theorem you can always take the indecomposable groups in your pseudovariety as a base (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull–Schmidt_theorem)

Comment: Oh yes, my question was too naive; it does make sense to take all the indecomposable groups as a base. I was hoping to see some more examples of pseudovarieties whose bases have a "nice" description (like in the case of finite nilpotent groups and finite abelian groups)

Comment: Do you maybe want some non-redundancy condition to your notion of "Basis", say that any subset of the basis fails at having the product representation property ?

Comment: @JoshuaZ, the indecomposable groups in the pseudovariety form the unique minimal basis.  They must be included because they cannot be decomposed as a direct product and the Remak theorem shows they suffice

Comment: The only candidate for a "basis" is the set of groups in the collection that are directly indecomposable within the collection (so I'm not sure "basis" is worth a name) — and since your class is closed under taking subgroups, these are just indecomposable groups of the collection. Since you consider only finite groups, this one works (as Benjamin Steinberg told you).